# Ppolyspace error: Read/Write access problem sources_list.txt (errno=13)

Tags: matlab, fatal-error, static-analysis

I'm trying to execute an analysis in polyspace. After the selection of the folder where there are the source files (.c) and the header files (.h), when I click on Run Bug Finder, I get the following message error:

```
Error: Polyspace : Read/Write access problem on C:\Users\Gennaro\Desktop\prova\Module_1\BF_Result\sources_list.txt (errno=13)
```

Can you tell me how to overcome it?

Every user has a full control of the folder.

---

EDIT: the resource monitor in Windows 10 didn't find any process that is locking the file sources_list.txt, and this file doesn't exist in the above folder.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some other program (like an editor) has an handle to the file open without the needed sharing mode?

Comment: Hello @BenVoigt can you tell me how to check that please?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1980/28549 gives examples of using tools from the SysInternals division of Microsoft to find out what program has a file open/locked.

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt I tried with the Resource Monitor tool in Windows 10, but it didn't find any associated process (the file sources_list.txt doesn't exist in the folder).

Comment: "The file doesn't exist".  That might be the cause of an error trying to read it.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's quite strange that polyspace requires a file that doesn't exist; moreover it's a txt file so it should not be essential.

Comment: From what I was able to read from google searching (Mathworks doesn't allow the public to read the full documentation) the graphical method for picking files is probably supposed to write the file names to that file, then use the `--sources-list` when invoking polyspace itself so that polyspace can know what files you picked.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help @BenVoigt, I will try another way to do it